# Expression language implicit objects

Tags: jsf, el

How can the JSF implicit objects be access via expression language?

For example, if I wanted to determine what roles the current principal is associated with, how could I do this?

Answer (score 5):

If you're using JSF on JSP, then you can do it just the same way as you would do in "plain JSP EL".

```
#{pageContext.request}
```

If you're using JSF on Facelets, then you can omit the `pageContext` part from the way as you would do in "plain JSP EL".

```
#{request}
```

Either way, it returns the [`HttpServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) object.

However, the only method which determines the user role is the [`isUserInRole(String role)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#isUserInRole%28java.lang.String%29) method. You can't pass arguments to methods in standard EL. You can however do that when you replace standard EL by JBoss EL.

```
#{request.isUserInRole(role)}
```

To install JBoss EL, just put [jboss-el.jar](https://maven.atlassian.com/content/repositories/jboss-releases/org/jboss/seam/jboss-el/2.0.0.GA/jboss-el-2.0.0.GA.jar) in `/WEB-INF/lib`  and add the following to the `web.xml`, assuming that you're using Mojarra:

```
<context-param>     
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>   
</context-param>
```

Comment: BalusC, thanks for the help.  I've just upgraded to Tomcat 7, which has updated support for EL.  I'm going to give this a go and see if it works.